# How I implement a view holder in an activity

Tags: android, button, textview, android-viewholder

How I implement a view holder?

```
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code, txtv;
        CheckBox name;
        Button btnnn;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.abb_list, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.btnnn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            holder.txtv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    checkTable country = (checkTable) cb.getTag();
                    country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.btnnn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             int counter = 0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                counter++;

                holder.txtv.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }
        });

        checkTable checkTable = itemsList.get(position);
        holder.code.setText(" (" + checkTable.getitemprice() + ")");
        holder.name.setText(checkTable.getitemname());
        holder.name.setChecked(checkTable.isSelected());
        holder.name.setTag(checkTable);


        return convertView;

    }

}
```

when i'm doing `holder.txtv.setText(String.valueOf(counter));` so it show me an error `Cannot refer to the non-final local variable holder defined in an enclosing scope` suggest me how I solve this issue.

Comment: the variable **holder** must be final. **An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: The title is also a little bit misleading. The problem isn't mainly about the holder pattern. It is about how variables are used in anonymous class.

Comment: Accept an answer if you are done. Happy coding. :)

Comment: @oberflansch You're right. But if the holder pattern were used properly, the author wouldn't have had this problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `final` `TextView` for the Listener:

```
final TextView counterTxt = holder.txtv;
holder.btnnn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter++;
        counterTxt.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a few variables outside the method, as private variables:

```
private TextView counterTx;
private int counter;
private ViewHolder holder;
```

EDIT: I believe this would be a better implementation that declaring these variables as `final`, as you would not be able to change their values afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you moving **findViewById** and **View.OnClickListener** to ViewHolder. Also keep a checkTable reference inside it. This will make the code  cleaner.

This kind of style is learned from [RecylerView.ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html). [RecylerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) aims to replace ListView and should be used in the future projects.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.abb_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    checkTable checkTable = itemsList.get(position);
    holder.country = checkTable;
    holder.code.setText(" (" + checkTable.getitemprice() + ")");
    holder.name.setText(checkTable.getitemname());
    holder.name.setChecked(checkTable.isSelected());

    return convertView;
}

// Try to use static inner class as possible as you can, this will eliminate
// many strange issues.
private static class ViewHolder implments View.OnClickListener {
    checkTable country;
    TextView code, txtv;
    CheckBox name;
    Button btnnn;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        view.setTag(this);
        code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        btnnn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        txtv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        name.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnnn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnnn) {
            // ViewHolder will be reused, you better move counter to checkTable
            checkTable.counter++;
            txtv.setText(String.valueOf(checkTable.counter));
        } else if (v == name) {
            country.setSelected(name.isChecked());
        }
    }
}
```